# "ERROR: query has no destination for result data", when trying to return results in a temp table. Using Postgres 13.1

Tags: postgresql, temp-tables

The code is simply looping to load a row for every 15 minutes from the start time to ending time, within one day.  Once I get this working I will be adding more data into the temp table before it gets passed back to the caller.

I will be doing more processing, later on, by loading more data into that temp table, I just wanted to see if I could load the temp table and pass it back out of the function.  I get the error as in the "Title Line" ERROR: query has no destination for result data when trying to return results in a temp table. Using Postgres 13.1   Any help would be greatly appreciated . . . Thanks!

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION uf_getAllProviderAppts(
in
    in_loc_id       bigint, 
    in_appt_str_dt  date,
    in_appt_str_tm  char(8),
    in_appt_end_dt  date,
    in_appt_end_tm  char(8),
    in_duration     int, 
    in_provider     bigint
) 

RETURNS table( loc_id bigint, appt_str_dt date, appt_str_tm char(8), appt_end_dt date, appt_end_tm char, staff_id int, pat_name varchar, visit_reason varchar ) AS

$BODY$
DECLARE
    appts tb_tmpOpenAppts%rowtype;
   
DECLARE   
    wk_str_tm time without time zone;
    wk_end_tm time without time zone;
   
begin
    
    CREATE TEMP TABLE IF NOT EXISTS tb_tmpOpenAppts
        (
            loc_id          int8         not null,
            appt_str_dt     date         not null,
            appt_str_tm     time without time zone,
            appt_end_dt     date         not null,
            appt_end_tm     time without time zone,
            staff_id        int8         not null,
            pat_name        varchar(50)  not null,
            visit_reason    varchar(128)            
        );

    select cast( in_appt_str_tm as time) as wk_str_tm ;
    select cast( in_appt_end_tm as time) as wk_end_tm ;

    
/* Loop creating open time slots for this Provider */   
    Loop
                
        insert into tb_tmpOpenAppts(loc_id, appt_str_dt,    appt_str_tm, appt_end_dt,    appt_end_tm, staff_id, pat_name,  visit_reason )  
                             values(1,      in_appt_str_dt, wk_str_tm,   in_appt_end_dt, wk_end_tm,   4,        'Open',    '');
    
        set wk_str_tm = wk_end_tm ;
        wk_end_tm = (select wk_end_tm + in_duration) ;
                             
        if wk_end_tm > cast(in_appt_end_dt as time) then
            Exit;
        end if;
    
    End Loop ;

    RETURN Query 
        select * from tb_tmpOpenAppts where loc_id > 0 ;

   IF NOT FOUND THEN
        RAISE EXCEPTION 'No Appointments at %.', $2;
   END IF;   
    
 /* Loop to return all open appts - Testing only */
/*----------------------------------------------*/
/*    LOOP
        RETURN NEXT appts; 
    END LOOP;*/
        
   RETURN;
  
END;

$BODY$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Following is the select I was using to test it with:

SELECT * FROM uf_getallproviderappts( 1, date('12-10-2020'), '08:00:00', date('12-10-2020'), '17:00:00', 15, 4 );

Also, I had to create a dummy table to get the thing to syntax check ok.

Comment: The full error message would be helpful. I'm guessing it it this: `select cast( in_appt_str_tm as time) as wk_str_tm ;`(and the one that follows). That should be: `select cast( in_appt_str_tm as time) into wk_str_tm ;` See [SELECT INTO](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-SQL-ONEROW). Actually could just do `wk_str_tm time without time zone := in_appt_str_tm::time`.